# $f$ is continuous if preimage of subbasic open sets are open.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subbasis for $Y$. Then if for every open set $S \in \mathcal{S}, f^{-1}(S)$ is open in $X$ then $f$ is continuous. Would a proof for this just be any basis element $B$ in a basis $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as $B=S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n$ for some $S_1,...,S_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$ and any open set $U$ can be written as $U=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J}B_\alpha$ and since $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(S_1) \cap \cdots \cap f^{-1}(S_n)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ is open if each $f^{-1}(S_i)$ is open and $f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J}f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ is open for each $\alpha$ then $f^{-1}(S_i)$ open for each $S_i \in \mathcal{S} \implies$ $f$ is continuous.

What would be a better way to show this by explicitly writing each open set $U \in Y$ as a union of intersections of subbasis elements to do this, using correct notation? Also would my proof be completely correct even though I neglect to do this?

Comment: What you’ve done is fine. And if you’ve already shown that $f$ is continuous if preimages of basic open sets are open, then you can stop after observing that preimages of basic open sets are open whenever preimages of subbasic open sets are open.

Comment: One minor point: I think you should talk about *the* basis $\mathcal{B}$ arising by forming finite intersections of sets in your subbasis $\mathcal{S}$. There may be bases that don't arise in that way from your subbasis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this simply holds because $f^{-1}$, as an operation on subsets, commmutes with all unions and intersections.

Or say abstractly (a la measure theory): Define $\mathcal{T}'=\{O \subseteq Y\mid f^{-1} \text{ open in } X\}$

By the property in the first paragraph $\mathcal{T'}$ is a topology on $Y$ (the so-called final topology on $Y$ wrt $f$). By the *assumption* it contains $\mathcal{S}$ and because the definition (at least **mine**) of a subbase for $\mathcal{T}$ says that $\mathcal{T}$ is the *minimal* topology that contains $\mathcal{S}$, it follows that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T'}$ and this implies $f$ is continuous.